# I can't read the body of an email

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-8, laravel-9

I'm using the **laravel-imap package** to read my *PEC emails* from a management system.

For the uninitiated, the *PEC* is the Certified Electronic Mail, "*Posta Elettronica Certificata, (PEC)"*, it is the system that allows you to send e-mails with legal value equivalent to a registered letter with return receipt.

I can read the Subject thanks to the `getSubject()` method, I can count the number of attachments but **I can't read the body of the email**.

I also tried to use the `getHTMLBody()`, `getTextBody()` methods but I get nothing, i.e. I get a blank string.

I tried doing a

`dd($message->getHTMLBody(true));`

but I get **null**.

This is my code:

```
public function mail()
    {
        $oClient = Client::account('default');
        $oClient->connect();
        $folders = $oClient->getFolders();

        /** @var \Webklex\PHPIMAP\Folder $folder */
        foreach ($folders as $folder) {

            /** @var \Webklex\PHPIMAP\Support\MessageCollection $messages */
            //$messages = $folder->messages()->all()->get();
            $messages = $folder->query()->since(now()->subDays(30))->get();
            
        }
       
        foreach($messages as $message){
            echo $message->getSubject().'<br />';
            echo 'Attachments: '.$message->getAttachments()->count().'<br />';
            echo $message->getHTMLBody(true);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me please? I'm desperate.

Comment: I don't know anything about PEC, although I see there's an RFC for it. Is it compatible with IMAP? Have you tried accessing the service with an IMAP desktop client?

Comment: yes it is compatible with imap, there is no doubt about that

Comment: maybe it's a different format than usual?

Comment: Are you sure the email actually contains a body with content? Try calling `getBodies()` and see if the array is empty.

Comment: ^ array:1 [▼
  "text" => """
    
    
    
    """
]

Comment: @levi I get the mess just written above

Comment: @Sarah Looks like the body contains text, of an empty string. Have you tried another IMAP client, to see if it shows something different?

Comment: yes i tried, it shows the exact same thing

Comment: Its possible to send an email, with an empty body. So it might be functioning correctly, and the email sender is at fault for it being empty.

Comment: with getStructure() I get the body. Only it's all messy and I can't handle it in code

Comment: no it has text with attachments in it

Comment: The structure can contain attachments but no body. See here - https://github.com/Webklex/php-imap/blob/d88eddb3e567f24a3630014d0de4457bce0526ab/src/Message.php#L538

Comment: I think the parsing is working correctly. the messy text you see, is simply the way of encoding the attachments.

Comment: in the raw property I notice that it shows me something about the content

Comment: So what should I do? If I would like to read text from it how could I do?

Comment: Please use an email client which is capable of reading the email and let use know the actual contents of the email (e.g. contents in the eml file)